# How to properly implement optimistic locking for related entities in JPA

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, locking

Below is the simplified version of my data model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DATA_TABLE")
public class DataTable implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "DATA_TABLE_ID")
    private int dataTableId;

    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dataTableId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Row> rows;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    private long version;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ROW")
public class Row implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ROW_ID")
    private int rowId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DATA_TABLE_ID")
    private DataTable dataTable;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dataTableId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Row> rows;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CELL")
public class Cell implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CELL_ID")
    private int cellId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROW_ID")
    private Row row;

    @Column(name = "TEXT")
    private String text;
}
```

I need to implement the optimistic locking for that model that is compatible with existing system. 
In it, the version from the DataTable is sent to the user of the service, they have to send it back alongside the acion they performed and this is used to verify that there were no changes in the meantime. The version field is updated whenever there is a change to Row or Cell that belongs to that particular DataTable.

Unfortunately this does not seem to work with JPA @Version annotation(Hibernate 4.1.9). The `version` field is updated when there is a change to the properties persisted in `DATA_TABLE` table, e.g. `title`, but changing/adding rows and cells does not increment the `version` value.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality in JPA either by @Version or some other mechanism(expicit locking?) that prevents concurrency bugs such as [Time of check to time of use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOCTTOU)?

Comment: You want that the @ Version to be applied in all table? The @Version will not change if you add more rows to the table or more columns via database GUI.

Comment: have you solved this issue? if yes, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the field you're mapping to is a primitive type (`long`). You should use the Wrapper type `Long` instead.

Comment: It did not help. Sorry if I didn't make myself clear. The `@Version` optimistic locking works fine, i.e. OptimisticLockException is thrown when there is a wrong version number on the entity I am trying to commit. However this version is not incremented when one of the related entities(owned by the one with `@Version` annotation) is changed.

Answer (score 1):

JPA maintains a version number for every entity object. The initial version of a new entity object (when it is stored in the database for the first time) is 1. In every transaction in which an entity object is modified its version number is automatically increased by one. Version numbers are managed internally but can be exposed by defining a version field.

During commit (and flush), JPA checks every database object that has to be updated or deleted, and compares the version number of that object in the database to the version number of the in-memory object being updated. The transaction fails and an OptimisticLockException is thrown if the version numbers do not match, indicating that the object has been modified by another user (using another EntityManager) since it was retrieved by the current updater.

This behaviour happen only if the row is changed .. the foreign keys don't matter therefore the version number doesn't increase.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The problem is what I really need is to take into account all changes made to all entities related to that versioned entity.

Comment: Maybe you could use a pessimistic lock and set a technical column to handle custom behaviour.

Comment: @TomaszW I guess if you add version field to all related object, they will have their versions respectively, so that when updating them, optimistic lock will work same way as for main entity. I didn't try this, but gonna try right now in the issue I'm facing myself currently